# Array output and adding a character

Tags: php

When the user hits submit I want the post data saved to a cvs file. i want to do an output of $valid[$var] into $cvsData with a "," after each variable... where do I been with doing something like this? Also I was looking at `fputcsv` would this give me the same result by putting the ","

```
    $valid = true; 
    foreach($_POST as $var => $value) { 
        if(empty($value)) { 
            $valid[$var] = false;
        } else {
            $valid[$var] = true;
        }
    }
```

// $cvsData = $phone . "," . $fn . "," . $ln . "," . $sos . "," . $e1 ."\n";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$line = "";
foreach($_POST as $value)
{
    if(!empty($value))
    {
        echo '"" . str_replace('"', '\"', $value) . '", ';
    }
}
$line = trim($line, '", ');
echo $line;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
$valid = true;
$csvHeaders=""; 
$csvData="";
foreach($_POST as $var => $value) 
{ 
    if(!empty($value)) 
    {
        $csvHeaders.=$var.",";
        $csvData.=$value.",";
    }
}

echo $csvHeaders;
echo $csvData;
```